Animated movie about a kid taking revenge on the gang that killed his father
I'm trying to find a specific animation movie (with colors) that I watched around 11 years ago when I was a kid.
Basically, a very young kid watches his father being chased by a gang, and eventually, having no other choice, the father jumps from a cliff and calls his son a farewell. The kid is very frightened and tries to survive in the woods in the time that comes after, there he grows. One day, he decides to revenge the gang, and after a journey he succeeds finding the gang members, probably kills them one by one in order to get to the ringleader whom ultimately he kills as well.
This was the plot, and besides I remember that a woman who was a member of the gang threw some hand fans as her weapon.
I also remember that in the opening scene, thunders were heard and lightning was seen, and the gang reached the kid's father in his house. The father broke the glass in order to escape them, but unfortunately failed.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

The description of hand fans as weapons makes me think it's an anime movie; can you remember whether that's the case?

@F1Krazy It's very likely that this is indeed the case
